# How to remove Wordpress interpretation of single and double line-breaks as '<br>' and '<p>' without breaking pre-installed theme?

Tags: wordpress

I know that there are a few workarounds to remove the interpreted single and double line-breaks as 'br' and 'p', my question is will it (and if so how to avoid) breaking a pre-made theme that I purchased?

In other words, I'm working on a theme a client purchased, I need to make some edits to it, but because of the 'translation' I can't style things properly; if I globally remove these wp filters, will the entire theme break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply your additional filters by either:

1. Creating a plugin. At the bare minimum you simply need the [standard plugin header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) so that WP detects it as a plugin and allows you to activate it, then a function to apply the filters which you can hook in to the `init` action
2. Create a child theme. Child themes let you customise all kinds of aspects of the site without touching the parent theme. [Here's a fairly good guide on how to do it.](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/)

With either approach there should not really be any need for you to remove any filters, as you can always apply multiple filters to any particular text.